# Labelling, numbering and referring to a question

Tags: labels

I wish to typeset the following questions in latex

```
Q 1 Find the shortest path....                      
Q 2 Explain...
```

I want to type these questions under `\begin{question}......\end{question}` in latex and label each question to refer them later.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete but minimal example which reproduces your problem. As is, I'm afraid it's very difficult to answer to your question.

Comment: @Mico No, i don't wish to use exam document class

Comment: @Mico, you may resolve my problem with any suitable answer using exam document class or without using it, since i have no idea about this environment too. Yes, i am using asthm ntheorem environments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `ntheorem` package. It sets up a new theorem-like environment called `question`. Cross-referencing `question` environments can be achieved via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape} % or "\itshape", or whatever
\newtheorem{question}{Q}

\usepackage{cleveref} % optional (for \cref and \Cref macros)
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}

\begin{document}

\begin{question} \label{q:1}
Find the shortest path \dots
\end{question}

\begin{question} \label{q:2}                
Explain \dots
\end{question}

Questions \ref{q:1} and \ref{q:2} \dots

\Cref{q:1,q:2} \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i couldn't fix yet. I am not using \usepackage{ntheorem}, but working in the following environment:                             \documentclass[11pt]{article}                     \usepackage{amsthm, amstext}               \usepackage{amsmatch}                            \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

Comment: @gete - If you're not willing or able to use the `ntheorem` package, why did you indicate earlier that you do? Incidentally, I've never heard of a package called `amsmatch` before. Does your code compile without errors?

Comment: @gete - If you must use the `amsthm` package, all you have to do is replace `\theoremstyle{plain} \theorembodyfont{\upshape} \newtheorem{question}{Q}` with `\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{question}{Q}`.

Comment: Thanks. Its fixed now